# Are there monadic/applicative map (i.e. traverse/mapM) functions over ByteString or Text?

Tags: haskell, text, dictionary, traversal, bytestring

There are standard (pure) map functions for [ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#g:4) and [Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html#g:7):

```
map :: (Word8 -> Word8) -> ByteString -> ByteString
map :: (Char -> Char) -> Text -> Text
```

but I'm missing their monadic/applicative counterparts:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f) => (Word8 -> f Word8) -> ByteString -> f ByteString
traverse :: (Applicative f) => (Char -> f Char) -> Text -> f Text
```

(If we have `traverse` we can define `mapM f = unwrapMonad . traverse (WrapMonad . f)`.)

I tried looking through the packages, tried Hoogle, but I didn't find them. Did I overlook something? Or is there a reason why they're missing (like it's not possible/easy to define them efficiently)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need them for?

Comment: Not being the author of either package, my guess is that the definitions would be quite ugly.  It would seem to involve a lot of interleaving `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov I'm trying to make a few enhancements to the [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike) package. In particular, monadic/applicative traversal over elements. Current implementation does it by converting the collection to a list and then folding `snoc` over it, which is very inefficient.

Comment: there are `ByteString.head` and `ByteString.tail` - if they are pointer operation underneath, traversing a ByteString with them may have decent performance.

Comment: @EarlGray AFAIK there are pointer operations underneath. `head` and `tail` are enough for folding. But the problem with traversing is that it also needs to rebuild the structure with modified elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally, you have exactly what you need in Edward Kmett's [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package; your desired `traverse` versions are simply `Data.Bytestring.Lens.bytes` and `Data.Text.Lens.text`.

**Edit:**  To clarify, the above-mentioned functions are of (a generalization of) type `SimpleTraversal c e` (for `(c ~ Bytestring, e ~ Word8)` and `(c ~ Text, e ~ Char)`, respectively), which is a type synonym for `forall f. (Applicative f) => (e -> f e) -> c -> f c`

Comment: Thanks, the package looks quite interesting. Do you know how efficiently are those method implemented? Do they go to the `ByteString`'s or `Text`'s internals, or do they do something like `pack . traverse f . unpack`?

Comment: @PetrPudlák Looking at [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.0.4/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Strict-Lens.html), it seems that it's just `pack . map f . unpack `